# tensorflow: tf.split is given weird parameters

Tags: tensorflow, neural-network, deep-learning, recurrent-neural-network

Here is code([from here](https://pythonprogramming.net/rnn-tensorflow-python-machine-learning-tutorial/)):

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.examples.tutorials.mnist import input_data
from tensorflow.python.ops import rnn, rnn_cell
mnist = input_data.read_data_sets("/tmp/data/", one_hot = True)

hm_epochs = 3
n_classes = 10
batch_size = 128
chunk_size = 28
n_chunks = 28
rnn_size = 128


x = tf.placeholder('float', [None, n_chunks,chunk_size])
y = tf.placeholder('float')
def recurrent_neural_network(x):
    layer = {'weights':tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([rnn_size,n_classes])),
             'biases':tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_classes]))}

    x = tf.transpose(x, [1,0,2])
    x = tf.reshape(x, [-1, chunk_size])
    x = tf.split(0, n_chunks, x)

    lstm_cell = rnn_cell.BasicLSTMCell(rnn_size,state_is_tuple=True)
    outputs, states = rnn.rnn(lstm_cell, x, dtype=tf.float32)

    output = tf.matmul(outputs[-1],layer['weights']) + layer['biases']

    return output
def train_neural_network(x):
    prediction = recurrent_neural_network(x)
    cost = tf.reduce_mean( tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(prediction,y) )
    optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer().minimize(cost)


    with tf.Session() as sess:
        sess.run(tf.initialize_all_variables())

        for epoch in range(hm_epochs):
            epoch_loss = 0
            for _ in range(int(mnist.train.num_examples/batch_size)):
                epoch_x, epoch_y = mnist.train.next_batch(batch_size)
                epoch_x = epoch_x.reshape((batch_size,n_chunks,chunk_size))

                _, c = sess.run([optimizer, cost], feed_dict={x: epoch_x, y: epoch_y})
                epoch_loss += c

            print('Epoch', epoch, 'completed out of',hm_epochs,'loss:',epoch_loss)

        correct = tf.equal(tf.argmax(prediction, 1), tf.argmax(y, 1))

        accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct, 'float'))
        print('Accuracy:',accuracy.eval({x:mnist.test.images.reshape((-1, n_chunks, chunk_size)), y:mnist.test.labels}))

train_neural_network(x)
```

I have issue understanding `x = tf.split(0, n_chunks, x)` , more specificaly third parameter(`x`-input). By [documenation](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/split) this should be axis...but that can't be, right? Isn't `x` one dimensional?
I apologise if it's trivial, I'm beginner and can't sem to get it. Maybe it's just formality, but if it is I don't understand how it works...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> By documenation this should be axis...but that can't be, right?

From tensorflow 1.0 onwards, the first argument of `tf.split` is not the axis, but I assume that the code was written using an older version where the first argument is indeed the axis.

> Isn't x one dimensional?

`x` is not one dimensional. Right before the call to `tf.split`, `x` is reshaped from 3 to 2 dimensions with this statement:

```
x = tf.reshape(x, [-1, chunk_size])
```

The statement reshapes `x` into a tensor with two dimensions: the size of the second dimension is `chunk_size` and the size of the first dimension is inferred (that is what the `-1` denotes here).

Comment: Thanks! But in `tf.split(0, n_chunks, x)` first argument is `0`(which should be data) and third is `x` which should be axis???

Comment: This depends on the tensorflow version. The order of the arguments of `tf.split` has been changed from version 0.12 to version 1.0. See https://www.tensorflow.org/install/migration.

Comment: For completeness sake [tf.split() documentation for v0.12](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.12/api_docs/python/array_ops/slicing_and_joining#split)